# Como colocar uma Function Arrow em no onclik

Tags: funções, onclick, arrow-functions

Como eu faço para colocar uma função Arrow Function em um onClik já que ela fica com o nome da variável?

Segue foto do exemplo:

[image: foto da minha função]

Answer (score 1):

Você pode colocar normalmente no onClick

```js
const log = () => {
  alert('debug')
}
```

```html
<button onClick="log()">LOG</button>
```

Comment: muito obrigado, ajudou muito.